# What issues does my phonetic notation question have?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [Advantages and disadvantages of learning a phonetic notation to learn Mongolian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/459/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-learning-a-phonetic-notation-to-learn-mongolian) has been closed, and has received no votes to re-open. By contrast, [Pros and cons of using IPA over other phonetic alphabets](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-ipa-for-language-learning) was closed but has since been re-opened.

What issues, if any, does my question have?

In particular, did enumerating the rationales I currently have for not learning a phonetic notation make the question seem biased?

Comment: I didn't VtC, so I'm not going to answer, but what if you generalized to all phonetically-spelled languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close-voter here. I can't comment on why others chose to close the question, but here's my rationale.

Questions asking for the "advantages and disadvantages" of something are always suspect, in my opinion. Whether a particular feature of something is an advantage, a disadvantage, or irrelevant depends heavily on the asker's specific situation. In a large majority of cases, the question would be better if it focused on *that situation* and the effects of the subject *on* that situation.

Expanding on that point, another problem that can show up with "advantage/disadvantage" questions is that they can end up being too broad. Usually, there are many possible advantages/disadvantages that could be listed, most of which, from the asker's perspective, would be considered irrelevant. To give an exhaustive answer that describes the advantages and disadvantages from a fully general perspective is often difficult, long, and not all that helpful.

---

In my opinion, the question would be better rewritten as one of the following:

- Will using phonetic notation to learn Mongolian interfere with my understanding of Mongolian Cyrillic?
- Does using a strictly phonetic notation help with learning pronunciation better than using normal spelling?
- Will using a Latin alphabet-based phonetic notation interfere with my learning of unfamiliar phonemes (in Mongolian)?

---

**TL;DR**: Advantage/disadvantage questions depend heavily on the asker's perspective, and would usually be better if they focused specifically on that perspective.

Comment: Same reason why I closed it too. Nice answer!